# How get values from ContainerView inside parent ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a view controller that use it as a login page.So I put login and cancel buttons and I want to use static table view for username and password fields. The problem is about static table view controller because I must put it inside a container view and have relation to it as a child view controller. I want to read text fields values when the user touches the login button.But because login button is inside parent view controller, I try to call exit segue to get values from text fields. But I can't do that and I don't know it's logical to do this action.

So in summary for this purpose is this way true or not and if true how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that by overriding `prepare` method.

1- From storyboard, give an identifier to the segue that embeds your login table view controller to the container, let's call it *loginEmbedSegue*.

2- Add a new property to the view controller that contains the container view like this:

`var loginTableViewController: LoginTableViewController`

3 - Inside the view controller that contains the container view, override `prepare` method in the following way:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

if segue.identifier == "loginEmbedSegue" {
    self.loginTableViewController = segue.destination as! LoginTableViewController
   }
}
```

4- Now, you have a reference to the the view controller that contains the username and password textfields.

Good luck!